# Adobe AIR and swf decompiler

Tags: flash, air, adobe

for my work, I obtained an application "Adobe AIR" from one client.I analyzed the software with "Swf DEcompiler" because i can't acces at the source code. during the analysis I discovered valeure static blocks the connection "application / server".
I can not change the value with SWF Decompiler, so I exported the entire contents of the application. "As".

My question is, how can I recompile the entire application in Adobe Air ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obtain source code from client too :-)

Comment: Yes, but I can not. The programmer to leave my client for many years and the client does not have the source code. IT was only the executable.

Comment: You need to recreate your project "from scratch" with Flash of Flex and compile. You have all sources, what's the problem? Just a little drudgery... :)

Comment: Thanks of your answer but I don't know the flash programmation and their tools